# Torsors over elliptic curves

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves, etale-cohomology

Let $G$ be a finite abelian etale group scheme over a number field $k$. Let $E$ be an elliptic curve over $k$ and $C := E\backslash \{O\}$ its affine model of the same equation.

Recall that for a variety $X$, the pointed (etale cohomology) set $H^1(X,G)$ classifies all $X$-torsors under $G$.

Given a torsor $Y \rightarrow E$ under $G$, the pull-back by the canonical inclusion $C \rightarrow E$ gives us an element whose class is in $H^1(C,G)$. Thus we have a map $$H^1(E,G) \rightarrow H^1(C,G)$$ defined by pull-backs.

I want to know if this map has any chance of being an isomorphism. There isn't much in the literature about the cohomology groups $H^i(E,-)$, usually $E$ is on the right, and therefore I hope to get references understanding $E$-torsors under some group rather than some $X$-torsors under $E$.

Comment: This is a question about etale fundamental groups of curves. Note that the curve $C$ has many more finite etale (Galois) covers than $E$. In fact, the fundamental group of $C$ is much larger than the fundamental group $\pi_1(E) = \mathbb{Z}^2$ of $E$.

Comment: @AriyanJavanpeykar Thanks for the information, is there an explicit relation between $\pi_1^{et}(E)$ and the group $H^1(E,G)$?

Comment: A $G$-torsor $V\to E$ is also a finite \'etale G-Galois morphism.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed this map is an isomorphism. There is a diagram of five-term exact sequences, arising from the Leray spectral sequence for the maps $E\to \text{Spec}(k), C\to \text{Spec}(k)$, from

$0\to H^1(k, H^0(E_{\overline{k}}, G))\to H^1(E, G)\to H^0(k, H^1(E_{\overline{k}}, G))\to H^2(k, H^0(E_{\overline{k}}, G))\to H^2(E, G)$

to the analogous sequence with $C$

$0\to H^1(k, H^0(C_{\overline{k}}, G))\to H^1(C, G)\to H^0(k, H^1(C_{\overline{k}}, G))\to H^2(k, H^0(C_{\overline{k}}, G))\to H^2(C, G)$.

By comparison with the complex-analytic setting, the map $H^i(E_{\overline{k}}, G)\to H^i(C_{\overline{k}},G)$ is an isomorphism for $i=0,1$. Hence this map of five-term exact sequences is an isomorphism on the first, third, and fourth terms.

We would like to argue that it is an isomorphism on the second term. But this is immediate from the five lemma.

Comment: This was actually what I had in mind! Based on what I've seen before, we use the spectral seqeunce $H^p(k,H^q(\bar{E},-)) \implies H^{p+q}(E,-)$. But how do you prove that the map $H^i(\bar{E},\bar{G}) \rightarrow H^i(\bar{C},\bar{G})$ is an isomorphism? This would be the same as saying that all finite abelian coverings of $\bar{E} = E \times_k \bar{k}$ arise through pull-backs from coverings of $\bar{C}$. Could you provide more details about the complex-analytic setting you were referring to?

Comment: Yes—by comparison it’s enough to check this over the complex numbers; but if G is an Abelian group G-covers are the same as maps $H_1\to G$, and the first homology of a 2-torus doesn’t change if you puncture it once.

Comment: (Put another way, the loop around the puncture is a commutator and hence goes to zero in any Abelian G.)

Comment: Thank you, the 2-torus you are referring to has to be the etale fundamental group of $E$, as mentioned in a comment to my question, right? Does the fact that $C$ is one point away from $E$ actually matter? Or can $C$ just be a finite number of points away from $E$ for the result to still hold?

Comment: @KelvinLian: The 2-torus is just the complex points of E itself. Re: deleting more points, the statement is false if one does so.

Comment: Ok, so $C(\mathbb{C})$ would be the punctured torus you mentioned. If I understood you correctly, given a fixed finite abelian group $G$, a $G$-cover of the 2-torus $T^2$ would correspond to a map $H_1(T^2) \rightarrow G$. So we have an isomorphism $H^1(E_{\mathbb{C}},G) \cong \mathrm{Hom}(H_1(T^2),G)$. But $H_1(T^2) = H_1(T^2\backslash \{\mathrm{pt}\})$, which gives us our desired isomorphism $H^1(E_{\mathbb{C}},G) \cong H^1(C_{\mathbb{C}},G)$ in the situation over $\mathbb{C}$. Is this correct?

Comment: Would you by chance have references to recommend me regarding the result that a given abelian $G$-cover is a map $H_1 \rightarrow G$?

Comment: @KelvinLian This is part of the theory of covering spaces; you can look in Munkres, for example (using that H_1 is the abelianization of pi_1).

Comment: Thanks for your time, I think the result you mentioned is somewhere along the line of Lemma 1 in https://www3.nd.edu/~andyp/notes/SeifertVanKampen.pdf